# C++ observer pattern with reference to custom container

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

I have a custom container (the "subject") which is observed by many other classes. Upon a change of the container, a notification is pushed to all observers after the change was made. E.g., for a resize, the process flow looks as

```
std::vector<double> vec;

void resize(size_t n)
{
    vec.resize(n);          //first resize
    notify(Event::RESIZE);  //afterwards inform observers about the resize event
}
```

Now, when I change elements of the container via reference access, I see no obvious way to do the notification:

```
double& operator[](size_t i)
{
    notify(Event::CHANGE_ELEMENT);  //no way to notify afterwards, so notify before
    return vec[i];
}
```

Thus when I change an element as

```
containerObject[2] = 1.1;
```

the observers get informed about an old state, which is updated only *after the notification*.

Is there a workaround (other than using a setter method) for this?

Comment: I believe your custom container shouldn't be providing operator[](size_t). May be a setter() and then send the notification from the setter after the change is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some kind of helper class, wich simply pushes the notification on destruction.

```
struct MyHelper
{
    //This is may be a friend of your container

    MyHelper(std::size_t index, MyCustomContainer& ref)
     : _index(index), _ref(ref)
    {  }

    ~MyHelper()
    { notify(Event::CHANGE_ELEMENT); }

    double& operator=(double rhs)
    { _ref._vec[_index] = rhs; }

private:
    std::size_t _index;
    MyCustomContainer _ref;
};
```

You can do this in your operator then:

```
MyHelper MyCustomContainer::operator[](size_t i)
{
    MyHelper m(i, *this);
    return m;

    // MyHelper Destructor called
}
```

Try it [online](http://ideone.com/0yz6MU)!

Comment: This still notifies before the new state is applied.

Comment: Thanks for the nice idea, even though it might not work.

Comment: @Jagannath: can you please explain more in detail why you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: Works now very well. :)
Problem before was, that the helper gets destructed before the actual operator= gets called. Thus this fiddling is needed.

Comment: As a remark, I find it easier to apply the notification directly in `operator=` after the new element was set. This you get rid of defining the destructor and eventually the related rule of three/five stuff (not that it's really necessary here).

Comment: You already worked around this possibility by returning `double&` from the assignment and not `MyHelper&`. I suggest to use type `void` here.

Comment: You should still consider to use a simple setter.

Comment: I really can't get how this got accepted. If MyHelper wants to access the private members of MyContainer , then MyContainer should make MyHelper a friend and the not the other way. In your case both of them are structs and hence the default access is public. So no issue with accessing MyContainer::_ref.